# Red Hat High Availabilty Oracle Resource Wallet Error

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, cluster

**Environment:** Running Red Hat 7.2, using Pacemaker 1.1.13-10.el7_2.2 and Corosync 2.3.4-7.el7_2.1 to implement cluster failover of an Oracle 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 Database.

**Background:** When I start the database outside the cluster, everything works correctly and outside queries from other hosts can execute.  The database has an encryption wallet which is set to auto-open, and which worked seamlessly before this problem cropped up.

**Problem:** When I add the oracle instance to the High Availability resource group, the instance starts up without any errors (that I can see).  However, when outside connections are attempted from other hosts, the database responds

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28365: wallet is not open
```

If I connect to the database on the host server and execute any queries, no errors are reported at the console, and the queries from remote hosts suddenly start to succeed again.  However, as soon as the cluster fails over to another node, the problem reappears.  The rejected queries cause trace files to be generated for the database SID containing:

```
kcbtse_get_tbskey: decrypting encrypted key for pdb 0 tablespace 6 without opening the wallet
kcbtse_get_tbskey: wallet is not opened (ts 0/6)
kcbtse_encdec_tbsblk: DIAG DUMP tsn 0/6 rdba 25165987, afn 6, mode 4
```

Has anyone seen this sort of issue before?  What is missing from the HA environment that is present outside of HA?

Comment: This might be better suited to Server Fault, possibly?